Show that the tangent cone is closed
Define the tangent cone as $T:=\{s \in \mathbb{R}^n|\exists\alpha_k\to0,\exists x_k \to \overline{x}:||\overline{x}+\alpha_ks-x_k||=o(\alpha_k)\}$ where $o$ is the small-o notation.
To show that $T$ is closed, I can take a sequence $c_k \in T$ with $c_k\to c$ and I need to prove that $c \in T$.
If I'm correct $||\overline{x}+c_ks-x_k||$ grows slower than $\alpha_k$. Then how would I show the same for $c$?
Thank you!
